# How can I save this model(s) and why is the use for “with tf.Graph().as_default()”

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I have been trying to train and then compile this RL algo. My problem comes when I want to save the three models.

Here is how the neural networks are defined:

```
def build_networks(state_shape, action_size, learning_rate, critic_weight,
               hidden_neurons, entropy):

state_input = layers.Input(state_shape, name='frames')
advantages = layers.Input((1,), name='advantages')  # PG, A instead of G

# PG
actor_1 = layers.LSTM(input_shape = (1,4),units=hidden_neurons, return_sequences = True)(state_input)
actor_2 = layers.LSTM(input_shape = (1,4), units=hidden_neurons, return_sequences = False)(actor_1)
probabilities = layers.Dense(action_size, activation='softmax')(actor_2)

# DQN
critic_1 = layers.LSTM(input_shape = (1,4), units = hidden_neurons, return_sequences = True)(state_input)
critic_2 = layers.LSTM(input_shape = (1,4), units=hidden_neurons, return_sequences = False)(critic_1)
values = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(critic_2)

def actor_loss(y_true, y_pred):  # PG
    #cusom loss-do stuff

# Train both actor and critic at the same time.
actor = models.Model(
    inputs=[state_input, advantages], outputs=[probabilities, values])
actor.compile(
    loss=[actor_loss, 'mean_squared_error'],  # [PG, DQN]
    loss_weights=[1, critic_weight],  # [PG, DQN]
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate))

critic = models.Model(inputs=[state_input], outputs=[values])
policy = models.Model(inputs=[state_input], outputs=[probabilities])
return actor, critic, policy
```

As you can see, the only NN that uses compile is the actor. How can I save the three NN for later use? Do I need to save them separate or I need to save the three NN as one? Also, when I tried to save them, I used this line:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    test_agent.actor.save_weights("Test_agent_actor.h5")
    test_agent.critic.save_weights("Test_agent_critic.h5")
    test_agent.policy.save_weights("Test_agent_policy.h5")
```

But when I try to load any of them, it says that:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in save file: the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
WARNING:tensorflow:Output dense missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to dense.
```

Even when I try to use the NN in validation/test dataset, I get an error that tells me that:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Tensor frames:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
```

Or when I try to save again the NN, it tells me something about "ragged" and the file size goes from 25MB to 1kb. Why is this? What I'm doing wrong? Should I use .hdf5 instead of .h5?

And also, I'm training all this with this part of code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
     #do some stuff
```

Why is this for? Why should I use this and also use `import tensorflow.keras` instead of `import keras`?

Thank you in advance!